# Unity3d application hanging on quitting

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have built an application with unity 3d that just streams data through USB and uses it.But while quitting the application, the application hangs, same happens when i am running from unity 3d engine, when i run it , it works fine, but once i quit, the engine hangs(Not responding). This happens only for this application. Any idea why this happens? I am using multiple system threads(C#), is that a probable cause ?

Answer (score 0):

Got the problem, i was not disconnecting the USB connection.